# How to use overlay in wescheme

Tags: wescheme

I want to use overlay function so that instead of 2 empty-scene i only get 1 empty-scene and both bitmaps are in the same empty-scene:

(define (grc r)
(bitmap/url "http://v.aimg.us/v2/system/assets/apps/android/000/144/676/icons/thirty.png?1324548547"))
(place-image (grc 25) 50 50 (empty-scene 200 200))

(define (wrc r)
(bitmap/url "http://img.photobucket.com/albums/1003/JJMaxx/RPG/diamond.gif"))
(place-image (wrc 25) 0 10 (empty-scene 200 200))

Any ideas? Is there any other was of achieving this?